# Cannot boot into operating system after installing ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I was installing ubuntu on a machine with Windows 10 through a USB thumb drive. While installing I selected the first option to "Erase whole disk and install ubuntu" and ignored one warning which went something like "It would be difficult to boot into the system". The installation was successful and when I rebooted the machine...It could not find any bootable media. I tried live booting and checked all my partitions were missing and could only see two disks, one on which I booted the system and other was my hard disk on which there was a linux file system. Is it possible to recover my previous partitions and windows OS along with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your last OS was Windows 10 I'm going to assume that the BIOS is attempting to boot into UEFI mode. Try setting it to legacy. Also, ensure that secure boot is disabled.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I can boot into ubuntu by setting boot mode to legacy. What I was wondering is that can I recover my Windows partitions and OS or at least my data with some recovery tools? I tried using photorec by testdisk through ubuntu live boot...But it shows around a 1000 hrs of ETA which is not practical!

Answer (score 0):

Data recovery is possible, but it will be costly.

Only deep states (intelligence, police, counter operation) have these tools available.

Few private companies that can handle this operation and will charge you a fortune.